# Adding formats to NSURL

Tags: objective-c

I want to add formate to mailto, by the formats are not adding to the mail please correct the code below if any thing is wrong..

```
NSString * msg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"xyz %@",x];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto://xyz@gmail.com&subject=Results&body==msg"]]; */
```

But msg object is not taking the value...

can anyone suggest me.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mailto://xyz@gmail.com&subject=Results&body==msg
```

You got one extra = in front of msg

Do something like this:

```
NSString *mailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?to=%@&subject=%@&body=%@",   address, subject, content];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mailString]];
```

Comment: Hi Peter ok, but how to insert formats like %@ or%i in this mailto is not taking formats?

Comment: see my updated answer it tells how to insert formats like %@ or%i in this mailto

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways here. One is to use `mailto` or use `MFMailComposeViewController`.

1. **Using mailto** - I use the simple method of composing an email and opening it with the Mail app. This also works as a confirmation; if the user doesn't want to send it, he can just cancel. So no need to add an 'Are you sure?' popup. He can also add a note or such.

> ```
>   NSString *mailurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:
> @"mailto:%@?subject=%@%@&body=%@%@",mailaddr,mailsubject,
> recipientname,mailmessage,mailsignature];
>
>   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
> [NSURL URLwithString:[mailurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
> NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
> ```

It works a charm and I use this method in several apps :)

1. **Using MFMailComposeViewController** - if you want to send email with proper compose, adding Cc, BCc etc. then try this - You have to use the `MFMailComposeViewController` class and the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol to send a mail...

> ```
> - (IBAction)buttonPressed 
> {
>     MFMailComposeViewController *mailController= [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
>     mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
>     [mailController setSubject:@"Hello iPhone"];
>     [mailController setMessageBody:@"This is the MailSend Application…." isHTML:NO];
>     [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
>     [mailController release];
> }
> ```

For your easiness in creating e-mail app your can refer to the [following link](http://mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-2-in-app-email-messageui/).

Comment: hi srikar, i don't want the compose box to open!!! it should send the direct mail once the button is press

Comment: and MFMailComposeViewController leaks memory - big time

Comment: but the code is failing, it says @"no class method for selector URLwithStrting"

Comment: @makumar it should be there. `NSURL` should be able to do this.

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo i wrote this code freehand in stackoverflow text editor. It was to give an idea of how mail sending works. If you feel you can fix the leaks, you are free to edit the code.